# OnlyOffice documents-app-ios project gives 'Invalid inputs' error all the time

Tags: onlyoffice

I was building open source Xcode project of only office editor for iOS
https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/documents-app-ios
Once the app is built and running I try to create new or open existing docx file and it always gives me error

`Documents[1273:186260] [Documents] ℹ️ INFO: Open file progress. Status: progress, progress: 1.0, error: Optional(Error Domain=com.onlyoffice.DocumentConverter Code=-1 "Invalid Inputs" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Inputs})`

The error comes from the document converter framework but here is no source code for it in the project (the project downloads it as a binary code) so I can not debug it.
Isn't it open source or hosted in another repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the absence of the conversion key.
The master branch has been updated with [the fix commit](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/documents-app-ios/commit/ed38f1b1a65efd4693e32a0fda39be6ca1cfa1ee). Please try again and let us know.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you! But now I get error that it cannot confirm license and document will be available in read only and yes from source code I see we pass .lic file (empty path). Where can I get that file?